# Java - Getting the value of a method inside of a class

Tags: java

I am trying to get the value of a method that is inside a class into the main class.

The code is supposed to let me give the variables 'a', 's' and 'u' each a value by using the console and afterwards return the values to the main class.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Auslesen 
{

    String a;
    private int s;
    double u;

    public class Scannen
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        public int Methode()
        {
            s = scanner.nextInt();
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my main class:

```
public class Start 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        Auslesen auslesen = new Auslesen();
        //System.out.println(auslesen); 

        Auslesen.Scannen scannen = auslesen.new Scannen();
        //System.out.println(scannen);

        Auslesen.Scannen.Methode methode = scannen.new Methode();
        System.out.println(methode);
        //my approach which didnt worked out...


    }   
}
```

Comment: Why you think you can call a method like `new [Methodname]"? Do you know what `new` means?

Comment: Just call the methods and store the result. Such as: 

    s = Methode(); 

Note that you are going to have a different problem soon i suppose... Note what types the variables are, and note that you have only one method signature defined... Think about that (public int Methode)... In that sense also note that Java does not support return type overloading.

Comment: Also, what is the reason for that inner class? If you really need to wrap this in a class then make one static class Auslesen, that contains the static helper 'Methode'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Methode` is a method not a class. You don't create it with `new` or create it at all for that matter. A method is defined in a class and you just call it. E.g.

```
System.out.println(scannen.Methode());
```

and delete this line :

```
Auslesen.Scannen.Methode methode = scannen.new Methode();
```

Also try to stick to the Java naming convention : class names start with uppercase method and variable names with lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you declaring a class inside another class ? If you simply want to return a value from one class to another class then you can do something like this -

```
String a;
private int s;
double u;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public int Methode()
    {
        s = scanner.nextInt();
        return s;
    }
```

now in the main method just call the method -

```
Auslesen a=new Auslesen();
System.out.println("The entered number is: "+a.Methode());
```

Comment: With the obvious comment that Methode in this case then would not set the variables, just return to the outstream... Depending on if it is a requirement in OPs assignment to do that or not. 

My interpretation is that values are to reside in the main class given OPs comment: " return the values to the main class." <- Note 'values' in plural here...